# Click on jsp <span> tree element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a tree element from a jsp page. When clicking this `span` tag then I get more of the tree.

```
<span class="tree " onmouseout="onMouseOutTreeNode(this)" onmouseover="onMouseOverTreeNode(this)" onclick="onToggleTree('product_main', this)">
    Categories
</span>
```

Any recommendations how to click with selenium on this span element to expand it more?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

All these tree elements look the same. The only difference is their tag text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code (**Assuming, there is just a single span tag in the webpage, with innerHTML/text as "Categories"**) :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='tree ' and contains(text(),'Categories')]")).click();
```

Comment: I tried it, however, selenium does not find it on the page? Which version of selenium do you use?

Comment: My selenium version is **2.44.0**. Please tell me two things. Are there multiple span elements with same innerHTML/Text as 'Categories' ? And, what exception are you getting when you run the above code ?

Answer (score 2):

vote up for the answer, what concerns your further issues, if your code is really as posted so the class being with the blank, you need to access it via xpath with the blank as well

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='tree ' and contains(text(),'Categories')]")).click();
```